# Плагины с вордпресс работают на самописе?

Tags: php, wordpress

Плагины с вордпресс работают на самописе?

Comment: Теоретически да, если воспроизвести внушительную часть API Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагины WordPress обычно широко используют функции ядра, подключаются ядром в определённый момент, пользуются базой WordPress.

Я не могу себе представить плагин WordPress, который смог бы работать на самописном php сайте.